# How can I remove background a plot in plot_model

Tags: r

Is it possible to remove the background color and the grids in the function plot_model
[image]

```
plot_model(mod, type="pred", show.p = TRUE, axis.title = "Ancho (m)", title = "")
```

and how can I change the size and the font of the labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
library(sjPlot)
library(ggplot2)

mod <- glm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)

set_theme(base = theme_classic(), #To remove the background color and the grids
          theme.font = 'serif',   #To change the font type
          axis.title.size = 2.0,  #To change axis title size
          axis.textsize.x = 1.5,  #To change x axis text size
          axis.textsize.y = 1.5)  #To change y axis text size

plot_model(mod, type="pred", show.p = TRUE, axis.title = "Ancho (m)", title = "")
```

[image]

Comment: How can I change the size of the axis labels?

Comment: Change the `axis.textsize.x = 3` and `axis.textsize.y = 3` to change the size of the axis labels. Don't forget to accept it as an answer to your question by clicking the tick mark below the upvote and downvote.

Comment: is it possible to exclusively remove the grey?